# how to move files from an encrypted home to a new one?

Tags: permissions, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

Yesterday I have recovered (not reinstalled) Ubuntu 16.04 in the same partition of my old home, so I created a new home with a different name, a new password and a new passphrase .
I have lost all the programs previously installed (no big deal) but all of my files in the old home (pics, video etc etc) are ok, they were spared.
Now I have an encrypted old home, and with ecryptfs I'm able to see (but not move/edit) the files in temp.

I dont want to make ecryptfs every time I launch Ubuntu, I want to move the contents of my old home  in the new home once and for all...

How can I do it?

If I try to use `chown` or `chmod 777` on the decrypted home in `temp`, the terminal say to me that it is a read only file system....

Thank you in advance